# Android Studio shortcut to show difference of a class from within that class

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard **shortcut** in Android Studio to **show difference** of class file, as compared to last commit, **from within that class**.

Currently I can see file difference from `VCS (Local Changes)` tab only by either selecting file and pressing `Ctrl + d` or from menu, as shown in image. There is another way but it involve number of mouse clicks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such a shortcut by default, you could always assign it yourself, but there is the operation you need

(you could search for any operation using another shortcut `Cmnd + Shift + A`) :

[image]

In order to assign a shortcut to the operation, you should go to `Preferences` -> `Keymap` -> search for 'Compare with the Same Repository Version' and assign a shortcut on it.

Comment: Thanks, assigned Alt+d as it was free